# Trouble while formatting a Discord message via `.join`

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to get my message to look like:

> **Ban List:**
>
> • User 1 ID (User 1 Name#User 1 Discriminator)
>
> • User 2 ID (User 2 Name#User 2 Discriminator)
>
> • User 3 ID (User 3 Name#User 3 Discriminator)

I've already gotten the user's id, name, and discriminator in list formatting, I just can't figure out how to get it to format correctly. I've been messing around with `.format` and `.join` for a while now, but can't figure out how to get it in the right order without each piece of data being on a new line.

For reference, this is what my code looks like now:

```
userid = ['User 1 ID', 'User 2 ID', 'User 3 ID']
name = ['User 1 Name', 'User 2 Name', 'User 3 Name']
discriminator = ['User 1 Disc', 'User 2 Disc', 'User 3 Disc']

total = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(userid, name, discriminator)))


await client.send_message(message.channel, "**Ban List:** \n •<@{}>".format(">\n• <@".join(total)))
```

This outputs:

> **Ban List:**
>
> • @User 1 ID
>
> • <@User 1 Name>
>
> • <@User 1 Disc>
>
> • @User 2 ID
>
> • <@User 2 Name>
>
> • <@User 2 Disc>
>
> • @User 2 ID
>
> • <@User 2 Name>
>
> • <@User 2 Disc>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code below, it's not a oneliner, but I guess it's more readable

```
userid = ['User 1 ID', 'User 2 ID', 'User 3 ID']
name = ['User 1 Name', 'User 2 Name', 'User 3 Name']
discriminator = ['User 1 Disc', 'User 2 Disc', 'User 3 Disc']

total = list((zip(userid, name, discriminator)))

# reformat the code into the desired formatting
pretty_list = set()
for details in total:
    data = "•<@{} ({}#{})>".format(details[0], details[1], details[2]) 
    pretty_list.add(data)

# debug print below
# print("**Ban list:** \n{}".format("\n".join(pretty_list)))

await client.send_message(message.channel, "**Ban list:** \n{}".format("\n".join(pretty_list)))
```

Goodluck :)

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens , I just updated the code to be more readable.
Assuming that you're asking the output, what it does is basically joining the properly formatted items inside ```pretty_list``` with a newline character("\n"). This joined strings are then "pasted" inside the placeholder```{}``` of the ```"*Ban list:** \n{}"```. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
userid = ['User 1 ID', 'User 2 ID', 'User 3 ID']
name = ['User 1 Name', 'User 2 Name', 'User 3 Name']
discriminator = ['User 1 Disc', 'User 2 Disc', 'User 3 Disc']

total = zip(userid, name, discriminator)

await client.send_message(message.channel, "**Ban List:** \n{}".format("\n".join(["• {}".format(" ".join(list(item))) for item in total])))
```

Comment: Tried it, but it just sends the same output but with spaces between them.

Comment: May you can replace the last sentence as below:
```await client.send_message(message.channel, "**Ban List:** \n{}".format("\n".join(["•<@{} ({}#{})>".format(*item) for item in total])))```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner (ish) solution:

```
userid = ['User 1 ID', 'User 2 ID', 'User 3 ID']
name = ['User 1 Name', 'User 2 Name', 'User 3 Name']
discriminator = ['User 1 Disc', 'User 2 Disc', 'User 3 Disc']

#convert [['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'b2']] to iter([('a1', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2')])
total = zip(userid, name, discriminator)

await client.send_message(message.channel, "**Ban List:**\n"
                          + "\n".join("• {} ({}#{})".format(*i) for i in total))
```

The output should be:

> **Ban List:**
>
> • User 1 ID (User 1 Name#User 1 Disc)
>
> • User 2 ID (User 2 Name#User 2 Disc)
>
> • User 3 ID (User 3 Name#User 3 Disc)